# How to follow pagination with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this target url:

```
<nav>
<ul class="pagination pagination-lg">
<li class="active" itemprop="pageStart">
<a href="moto.html">1</a></li>
<li itemprop="pageEnd">
<a href="moto-2.html">2</a></li>
<li>
<a href="moto-2.html" aria-label="Next" class="xh-highlight">
    <span aria-hidden="true">»</span></a>
</li><
</ul>
</nav>
```

but I cant select the next page link, I try with:

```
    next_page_url = response.xpath('./div/div/div[1]/nav/ul/li[3]/a').extract_first()
```

also with

```
response.css('[class="xh-highlight"]').extract()
```

I only get as result `[]` on the shell

other point: I set the user agent as google chrome because I read here about other user with problems on mark accents, but don't fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

I want to warn you Scrapy cannot scrape website rendered with javascript. Consider using a web driver like Selenuim with scrapy if the page is rendered in javascript.

I would recommend you go to scrapy shell, and type view(response). If you see a blank page than the page is rendered in javascript.

This is how you get urls from xpath, but I doubt it will make a difference sence you see no object

```
next_page_url = response.xpath('nav/ul/li[3]/a/text()')
```

Comment: i get this result with the shell
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xpath'

and if i see the view i can see the website withour problems

Comment: Did you set the url. For example, "scrapy shell url." Try this documentation https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html

Comment: @RahmiPruitt, that's not totally correct, `view(response)` will open the response on your browser and it will render any javascript inside the HTML, so, some dynamic content could still be rendered.  The best way to test it is to disable javascript execution on your browser and try to load the webpage.